# Designing Calculator in Swift - How to add single "." when require to enter floating point number?

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I am developing calculator in Swift for IOS8. When pressed [0-9] button. It displays correctly. Also operator [+ - / *] works successfully.

I would need to add "." button, so user can enter floating number 19.2, 21.67, 40.6725 - **How to write code so that "." appear once only, instead of 19.3.4?** (not legal floating point number in calculator)

I found out rangeOfString(subString: String) might be great use. It returns an Optional. If passed String argument cannot be found in the receiver, it returns nil

```
@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!
@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!

        if (digit == "․") {
            if (display.text.rangeOfString("﹒") != nil) {
               //DO Something Here
            } else{

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're 99% of the way there.  You only want to add the "." to your display if you don't already have one.  I'd suggest looking for `== nil` instead
of looking for `!= nil`.

```
    if (digit == "․") {
        if (display.text.rangeOfString(".") == nil) {
           // append "." to the display text because we
           // haven't see one yet

           display.text = display.text + "."

        } else {
           // do nothing, we already have a "." in the
           // display
        }
```

You can leave off the `else` clause.  I left it here for explanation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Vacawana's answer did't work out, as the syntax is out of date. I came up with simpler solution,

```
let dupDecimal = decimalDupCheck(inputDigit: digit, stringToCheck: display.text)
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
            if !dupDecimal {
                display.text = display.text! + digit
            }
        } else {
            display.text = digit == "." ? "0" + digit : digit
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = true
        }
    }
    func decimalDupCheck(inputDigit digit: String, stringToCheck text: String?) -> Bool {
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
            return digit == "." && text?.contains(".") == true
        } else {
            return false
        }
```

Basically you take in a `BOOL` function, checking for any duplication of ("."), and upon its result executes the next conditional brackets.